# Instagram ?__a=1&max_id=<end_cursor> isn't working for public user feeds

Tags: api, instagram

I've been using Instagram's undocumented API `https://www.instagram.com/<user>/?__a=1` to get a public user feed.

I was also able to get multiple pages via their `max_id` query parameter like so:  `https://www.instagram.com/<user>/?__a=1&max_id=<end_cursor>`

```
end_cursor = json_response.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor
```

(yes, "has_next_page" is true)

They had a recent change to their JSON format and I think they might have broken other functionality.

The "end_cursor" is still there but when I use it I just get back the same Instagram posts as if I wasn't using it.

Just to make sure I'm clear, my issue is that the `max_id=<end_cursor>` doesn't seem to work anymore for a public user feed. I can still get the first 12 posts, but no more after that.

Anyone else seeing this problem?

here's a JSFiddle example of what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/LLsg91ja/33/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

04-14-2018 - NO LONGER WORKING - INSTAGRAM DEPRECATED THE '?__a=1' & '?query_id=17888483320059182' - THIS NO LONGER WORKS!

Okay take a look at this for media pagination:

`https://instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&id=<user_id>&first=12&after=<end_cursor>`

This returns:

['data']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info']['end_cursor']

And Media:

['data']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']

the 'query_id' is static now so just use: 17888483320059182

'id' is the "instagram user id" so you have to use `?__a=1` to grab ['graphql']['user']['id']

'first' is the number of photos you desire returned. Just use 12 to keep the media return the same.

'after' is the new 'max_id' for use ['data']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info']['end_cursor']

I'll test more and respond later.

Responding Later:

It is believed 'pagination' using `?__a=1` has been deprecated. If true then there is no answer which can solve the op's direct question using `?__a=1` for Instagram pagination.

But the code provided in this answer will provide the pagination of Instagram media which does provide the results the op was seeking.

The answer incorporates the 'instagram graphql api' which is the current api (and not the json `?__a=1` hack) so this answer should provide some stability for now.

As used on my live site:

Grab the `id=<instagram_user_id>` prior the Instagram media request:

`profile = https://www.instagram.com/<instagram_username>/?__a=1`

`media = https://instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&id=<profile['graphql']['user']['id']>&first=12&after=<end_cursor>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question and should not be placed in the answer section

Comment: You need to create your own question. Everyone has earned the privilege and you are not an exception. Your comment in form of an answer will be deleted anyway. There is an audit always and the sooner you get to know the rules, the better you can use the forum

Comment: This actually worked!  check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/4LqnLhfg/12/  I just worry about the longevity of this technique.  But I guess that's the exact same case with the `?__a=1` technique as well. Where is that hardcoded `query_id` from and will that change?

Comment: @Francisc0 - the query_id is a permanent value (query_id=17851374694183129) which may change in the future: google it for dozens of example. And the code is from the latest changes to facebook/instagram graphql api so it may last a couple years. Also for a tag search try `https://instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&tag_name=<tag_name>&first=12&after=<end_cursor>`

Comment: @Francisc0 - using chrome/developer tools/network/XHR you can see IG calls the `?__=1` code first as to grab profile-data and load the first 12 photos `https://www.instagram.com/yanakozlova2007/?__a=1` and then pagination IG requests are `?query_hash=<hash>&user_id=<user_id>&first=12&after=<end_curser>` for additional pages of media (aka: no user profile-data). My guess is the `query_hash` identifies a cookie/session variables browser/mobile_device guest/logged_in_user, etc. If true, my guess is `query_id=1785137469418312` is a bypass to `query_hash` just to process the media requests faster.

Comment: NOT WORKING ANY LONGER - Francisc0 as of today April 7th 2018 the "?query_id=17888483320059182" has been deprecated. As @Igor Sovcik posted you can implement ?__a=1&page=n but you will need to query to see if current page contains 12 media assets ( ['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges'][11] ) - if less than 12 media assets then do not display/request next-page pagination.

Comment: @Mark: what is `n` here? not working for me. please explain

Comment: @arbaz-abid, so sorry about that. The 'n' represents the page "number" you want to request (aka: pagination): ?__a=1&page=1, ?__a=1&page=2, ?__a=1&page=3, etc.. This type of api call will only return 12 media assets at a time accompanied with the user's profile data. If 12 assets are returned you can paginate to the next  page as in  ?__a=1&page=n+1 or ?__a=1&page=n-1 to go to the previous page. So to make this method work you will need to keep track of the current page as a variable and then add +1 to "n" or -1 to "n". I hope this helps.

Comment: @Mark: I know how pagination works, sorry about my dumb question. Actually page=2, page=3 are not returning the paged media assets but only first page again and again. That's why I was thinking may be it was end_cursor. The solution Igor Sovcik gave isn't working for me.

Comment: @arbaz-abid, you are correct and I am incorrect. The &page=n is not returning the next page assets, only returns first page assets (weird it worked previously I thought). Currently ?query_id=params[:query_id] and ?__a=1&first=12&after=params[:end_cursor] are not working. I will try to solve this when time is available. (so sorry for the 'sophomoric' explanation of pagination - teaching my teenage daughters how to program, so sometimes I over-explain: dadsplaining)

Comment: I was using this query_id myself. Now it says forbidden. Request everyone to please post a solution here as soon as one finds.

Comment: `?__a=1` also gone :(

Comment: Where does the query_id come from? I don't see it in the json

Comment: @WilliamHampshire this is no longer working - both the query_id and __a=1 have been deprecated - to answer your question, the query_id was hardcoded as 'query_id=1785137469418312' - where the 1785137469418312 came from I have no idea. Again this no longer works. No alternatives as of this time.

Comment: Both query_id and a__1 have been deprecated; only way to successfully paginate through IG responses is using the official GraphQL API, which requires a Facebook Business Account tied to a Instagram Business account.

Comment: @Arbaz, I'm seeing that gramsave uses the following headers when requesting the next page: `{"username":"name_of_user","userid":"1527189853","page":"cOdeOfThePage"}`. Needs more investigation though....

Comment: This is working for me, i am not sure what you guys are saying it's gone, it's not. The __a=1 brings the first 12 images and the query_id brings the rest.

Answer (score -4):

You can use this: ?__a=1&page=3

Comment: This does not work even with hastags. &page=# has no effect.