# Instagram max_id not working

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We have been using below end point to fetch the Instagram feeds

> https://www.instagram.com/saintgobaingroup/?__a=1&max_id=

Later, for further feeds we use to fill the max_id parameter with last entry's id. It was working fine but now Instagram end point seems to have change the response format.
We are able to update the piece of code to match the response. However the max_id parameter seems to be not working now.

We are getting same 12 records even when we have more than 400 records. We are properly updating the max_id parameter like we use to do earlier. But we are unable to get further records only 12 records being getting repeated.

Any idea on this?

Note : As of now we're not focusing on using the Instagram API. We would like to get it done with end point `?__a=1`

Answer (score 0):

The answer doesn't work with ?__a=1, but it does get you pagination here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49266320/929540