# How to get comments from instagram publication

Tags: python, json, instagram

Is it possible to get more than 35 comments to the post after the instagram has introduced the changes using JSON?
As example code bellow:

```
import json
import urllib.request

def n_f_l(link):
    link_j = link + '?__a=1'  
    json_string = urllib.request.urlopen(link_j).read().decode('UTF-8')  
    parsed_string = json.loads(json_string)
    comments = parsed_string['graphql']['shortcode_media']
['edge_media_to_comment']['edges'] 
print(comments)


def main():
    n_f_l(link='https://www.instagram.com/p/BhfVd1env3K/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way I've got only 35 comments, is it possible to use End Cursor here? If yes, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem is that since 04-14-2018, Instagram has depreciated the '?__a=1' along with 'query_id=XXXX...' and because of this, there is no answer which can solve your question using `?__a=1` for Instagram pagination.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265013/instagram-a-1max-id-end-cursor-isnt-working-for-public-user-feeds/49266320) on a similar problem mentioned on this site.

The best option that I have found to get all the comments was using an unofficial Instagram API [here](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python/blob/master/examples/get_all_comments.py).